# Help with high school physics

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I am studying high school physics and it seems i have memorize the equation and use it mechanically in doing question and memorize lots of physical phenomena.I know a lot of physical phenomena can be explained by Huygen principle  (which i can't figure out the  whys and do not understand).There are so many things I don't understand and get the intuition.I know high school math and basic calculus,but it seems it doesn't help to understand.I am frustrated.I do not want to go along with memorizing and pass the exam as i think it is meaningless.We are not machines.Are there any resources that can help?Are there any books better explain high school physics and explain theories using math?

Comment: A search of the site showed various Young's slit experiment questions, but not one quite like this, but then there are so many I may have missed it - so answer posted below

Comment: I was in a situation like yours when I was in high school. I used (and still do) ask a lot of questions on websites like this one, as it can often be very hard to find information in a way that you can understand it. I would however recommend getting a physics book that covers lots of topics.

Comment: Unfortunately, you mention a great deal of physics here. The relative speeds of colors in materials is advanced optical materials physics, so there is no easy "derivation" of which way the dispersion goes - it comes down to frequencies of optical resonances in electron structures of the material. Some optical materials aren't even fully understood at a fundamental level. So unfortunately to understand much of this stuff other than at formula level takes a years of study. Huygens principle is a unifying thing that you could use to grasp a great many things at once, so I'd say go back ....

Comment: ..... and try Huygens's principle one more time. A great book that might help you with Huygens's principle is [Richard Feynman "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter"](http://www.amazon.com/QED-Strange-Theory-Light-Matter/dp/0691024170) - up to and including chapter 2.

Comment: but why red light itself has refractive index?not just material has?I asked that because the book mentions dispersion with angle of refraction of different light

Comment: While I symapthize, this question is *too broad*. Try asking more specific questions.

Comment: This question is too broad, and partly a rant against the education system in America.  To second @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance though, QED is a great book, and pretty accessible and you should start with that

Comment: i am not meaning to offend anyone.i just want to find some ways to understand physics

Comment: @bbrainb - please don't take any offence - the question has been closed as it is a duplicate - there are quite strict policies here about questions that aim to help the site run smoothly, but I hope that the discussion and both answers are helpful - do follow up on the QED book recommended by Rod and Sean - and do post more questions to this site :-)

Answer (score 1):

sorry to hear that things are frustrating. I don't think you need the Huygen principle for the double slit experiment. Take a look at the diagram below...
[image]

The diagram shows two rays from a double slit experiment.

The path lengths are slightly different from the two slits.

In one case the waves arrive in phase and you get the bright fringe - constructive interference.

In the other the waves arrive out of phase and cancel out and you get the dark fringe - destructive interference.

Now look at the image below
[image]

The difference in the path lengths is $s$ and you should be able to see from geometry that $s = d sin \theta$. The for contstructive intereference $s$ is a whole number of wavelengths and for destructive interference it is a whole number plus a half....

I hope that helps to understand where the formula comes from for Young's slits and makes things seem a bit more logical. - do comment.

Note that generally $L$ is a very long distance compared to $y$ and $d$ so that makes the two angles $\theta$ are so close in value to each other that we can treat them as the same angle

Comment: @tom.In the diagram you mark two angles( theta) are equal.How can you see it?

Comment: Yes,you dont need Huygens principle here but you need Huygens principle to understand how the light bends when passing through slits.

Comment: @bbrainb - with the angle - generally $L$ is a very long distance compared to $y$ and $d$ so that makes the two angles $\theta$ so close to each other that we can treat them as the same angle.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you are right.  Physics is tough, and in many ways high school physics is the hardest because it is the first introduction to a new and difficult way of thinking. Furthermore, teachers are under pressure to complete the curriculum.  And there's always the possibility that the teacher him/herself does not have a firm grasp of the subject.

It takes practice, and repetition, and struggle.  Read the book chapter many times.  Don't get stuck on a fine point that you don't understand: keep reading, and then read it again.  And again.  Work through the derivations in the book.  Write the down in your own hand.  Then do it again.  You are training your synapses.

Fortunately, it's easy these days to get alternate presentations on the Internet, and you can ask questions on physics forums.  There are several.  But watch out:  there are presentations out there that are just wrong, many of them written by high school teachers for high school students.

This is how everyone learns physics (unless you are Feynmann).  Consider the typical educational path of a physics professional:  you study mechanics in high school.  You will again when you take Introductory Physics in college.  Then again when you are a sophomore or junior when you take Classical Mechanics.  Then Classical Mechanics again in graduate school.  It's all about peeling the onion, one layer at a time, and that's what you have to do in high school.  Read once.  Read again.  And again.  Write the derivation once. Then again.  And again.  With each layer comes a little more understanding.

Formulas:  I don't see much value in memorizing them.  I believe that a teacher should allow a formula sheet.  With time and usage, the important ones will stick, and you will need the formula sheet only for the less common ones.  My memory is terrible.  I would never make it as a biologist.  But in physics, I don't have to memorize much.

Resource:  get access to one of the good standard texts:  Tipler, Halliday and Resnick, Knight, etc.   Work through it and struggle.

Comment: i think wave is more difficult than mechanics as mechanics is more math-related at least in high school physics

Comment: Math such as vector and calculus help me to understand mechanics

Comment: Mechanics was just an example.  The same thing applies to E&M, Quantum Mechanics, Statistical Mechanics, Solid State physics, ...

Comment: i don't know how to find the right material to study

Comment: sometimes the book is filled with so much terminology

Comment: That's what reading and re-reading and re-reading helps.